# How to create widget button that triggers button inside app

Tags: java

I'm using a button inside app to open storage settings. but I want to open storage settings with widget button.

```
 private void openStorageSettings() {               
      Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INTERNAL_STORAGE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);          
 }            
 private void openInstalledApps() {                 
      Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);           
 }
```

I'm using this code inside app to open storage settings. I got this from chatgpt.